# Cloud-init validator

Tags: cloud-init

Wondering if anyone knows of a validator that can validate cloud-init config similar to [this](https://coreos.com/validate/). We tried it and it gives a bunch of errors that are not applicable e.g., it does not recognize `package_update` which is a standard keyword that can be found [here](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#update-apt-database-on-first-boot) in the official documentation for example. So we are looking for a validator that works and recognizes the keywords in the official [documentation](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html).

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I hit this one recently too and found a nice way to do it.

In Ubuntu you can use the follwoing to validate the file parses correctly.

```
cloud-init schema --config-file bob.txt
```

This will give you the following notice if the files are valid or invalid

```
:~$ sudo cloud-init schema --config-file bob.txt
Valid cloud-config file bob.txt

$ nano bob.txt #edited the yaml to make it invalid
:~$ sudo cloud-init schema --config-file bob.txt
Cloud config schema errors: format-l2.c1: File bob.txt is not valid yaml. while parsing a block mapping
  in "<byte string>", line 2, column 1:
    package_upgrade: true
    ^
expected <block end>, but found '-'
  in "<byte string>", line 6, column 1:
    - 'curl -fsSL https://get.docker ... 
    ^
```

While your working with cloud init files `cloud-init status --wait` and many of the other commands on the `cli` are super useful.

Comment: This errors on `v22.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.3`: `/usr/bin/cloud-init devel: error: argument subcommand: invalid choice: 'schema' (choose from 'hotplug-hook', 'net-convert', 'render', 'make-mime')`

Comment: Is there any convenient way to install it locally on MacOS? Don't see it on brew.

Comment: no cloud-init on alma neither

Answer (score 7):

Starting from version [22.2](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/pull/1402), the cloud-init command to validate config file is now:

```
cloud-init schema --config-file conf.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an older version of cloud-init you may need to use:

cloud-init devel schema --config-file .yaml